# PHP Ifelse statement is true regardless

Tags: php, string, strtok, if-statement

Ok, I am now trying to expand on a bit of code that I had resolved here previously.
This code below assigns a phrase entered into a search box, and attempts to do the following:
1) clean out stuff I don't want in there (NOTE: The input is pre-processed so I am just stipping more off for now, and still working on this part).
2) break the phrase into individual words using spaces as the separator
3) check each individual word extracted to see if a * exists within the first 3 characters, and if so, abort the process
4) check if the words "and" or "or" are used - if so, apply them with no modification - if not, then insert an "and" to the phrase. (Ultimately converting the phrase to an "and" phrase automatically if the user doesn't specify it themselves).
5) Throughout the process, $keyword is reconstructed, and at the end I am echoing the final, new $keyword to test the result... of course more code follows then utilizing that new keyword.

```
if ($keyword)  {

            $clean = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 *_&]/','',$keyword);            
            $token = strtok($clean, " ");

            $keyword = $token;

            while ($token !== false) {
                $pos = stripos($token, "*");
                if ($pos < 3 && $pos !== false) {
                return;
                }
            $token = strtok(" ");
                if ($token == "and" || $token == "or") {
                    $keyword = $keyword . " " . $token; 
                } elseif ($token) {
                    $keyword = $keyword . " and " . $token;
                }
            }   
            echo $keyword;
```

PROBLEM:

Everything is working fine, except for some reason the ELSEIF statement is ALWAYS TRUE?!  No matter what I do, an extra ' and' is inserted, regardless of whether the if statement above it is true or not.  I have verified that the initial if statement does work, it detects whether 'and' or 'or' exists and applies it accordingly... but then it goes ahead and processes the ELSEIF anyways!!  I have even gone so far as trying:

```
elseif ($token !== "and" && $token !== "or" && $token !== false)
```

But in the end, the resulting phrase ends up with 'and and's or 'or and's, regardless.

(Note: I realize there are better options than preg_replace but I will be looking into that at another time - so for this question, I am just trying to resolve the ELSEIF dilemma, thanks)

---

APPENDING MODS Based on responses...

So, I changed the code to...

```
$token = strtok(" ");
                if (in_array($token, array( 'and', 'or' ))) {
                    $keyword = $keyword . " " . $token; 
                } elseif (!empty($token)) {
                    $keyword = $keyword . " and " . $token;
                }
```

But the results are still incorrect.  For example:

"white football helmut" does become "white and football and helmut",
however...
"white and football and helmut" becomes "white and and football and and helmut".

I just don't see how the ifelse can be processing if the if is true??

Note: To verify that the IF portion is working, I placed an x in that statement:

```
if (in_array($token, array( 'and', 'or' ))) {
                    $keyword = $keyword . " x" . $token;
```

And "white and football and helmut" results in "white xand and football xand and helmut".  Also, "white and football helmut" (no 2nd and) results in "white xand and football and helmut". !! So, the IF statement is processing as expected - just not the ELSEIF !!

Comment: Just a note, I think you may have missed a closing `]` in your regex just before the second `/`.

Comment: Good catch - I had more in there in my actual code, but removed most of it here in this message since it was a work in progress - and accidently clipped the ] off.  It's back on there now ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that both the current and previous tokens aren't "and"/"or".

```
$prevToken = $token;
$token = strtok(" ");
    if ($token == "and" || $token == "or"
       || $prevToken == "and" || $prevToken == "or" 
    ) {
        $keyword = $keyword . " " . $token; 
    } elseif ($token) {
        $keyword = $keyword . " and " . $token;
    }
```

Using "white and football helmut", the logic currently goes like this:

1. `$keyword` is initially "white"
2. Next token is "and," so it appends `" "` plus the token `"and"`. Now $keyword is `"white and"`.
3. Next token is "football," so it appends `" and "` plus `"football"`. Now $keyword is `"white and and football"`.

So that's how you're getting double "and". Check both current and previous tokens to avoid consecutive "and"/"or".

Comment: Ahhhhhhh.... ;-)  I can already tell this will work.  How was I not seeing that!! Forest from the trees again.  I will plug this in and test it out and reply back here shortly... THANKS

Comment: Yes, this works great, and addresses each requirement...  Thanks Wiseguy, you definitely have lived up to your name ;-)

Answer (score 2):

@Soyo: Try with this --

```
if ($token == 'and' || $token == 'or') {
    // do nothing here to avoid duplicating 'and'
}
elseif (!empty($token)) {
    $keyword = $keyword . ' and ' . $token;
}
```

**Update**

This is the script I use to test --

```
$keyword = 'white and and or and football and or helmut and';

if ($keyword)
{
    $clean   = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 *_&]/', '', $keyword);
    $token   = strtok($clean, ' ');
    $keyword = $token;

    while ($token !== false) 
    {
        $pos = stripos($token, '*');

        if ($pos < 3 && $pos !== false)
        {
            return;
        }
        $token = strtok(' ');

        if (in_array(strtolower($token), array('and', 'or'))) {
            // do nothing here!
        } elseif (!empty($token)) {
            $keyword = $keyword . ' and ' . $token;
        }
    }
    echo $keyword;
}
```

Comment: You could replace the first line with if( in_array( $token, array( 'and', 'or' ) ) { ...

for a more concise check.

Comment: @Soyo: See my updated answer. Note the `// do nothing here!` comment. This is where and why your script is inserting duplicate 'and's if you're going to tell it to.

Comment: Woops - didn't see your addition... there is another response here that approaches it in a different manner... so I will check out both and get back with results... THANKS much for your efforts!

Comment: p.s. great catch on strtolower - that is obviously required to do this right...!! ;-) as for the //do nothing, the reason I had code in there was to insert the spacing and address the 'or' which I still want to offer to the user. So, I tested this code and it is working great for AND (including spacing), however the or is not addressed... as such "football or helmut" becomes "football and helmut".  Greatly appreciate your input and help with this!

Comment: Ok, Wiseguy had the all encompassing answer, however I am also incorporating the key items presented here by Stealthninja, so overall thanks guys for the great help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're checking the wrong var in your `elif`.

Try this instead:

```
elseif ($keyword !== "and" && $keyword !== "or" && $token !== false)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding!  Well, if I were to check $keyword, it would be checking the entire contruction to that point, as $keyword is slowly being built up as the while process continues... so what I am trying to do with the elseif is say "ok, $token is NOT "and", and is NOT "or", so as long as it's not empty, append it to $keyword with an "and" in front of it...".

Comment: The ultimate goal is that if the user enters "white football helmut", this returns "white and football and helmut".  But, if they enter "white and football helmut", this should recognize that they used and, and the resulting phrase = "white and football and helmut", not "white and and and football and helmut"... hope this makes sense...